# error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker, and it is my first time meeting such error.

This is my DockerFile

```
FROM rust:latest as builder
ENV APP mapservice
WORKDIR /usr/src/$APP
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .
 
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/$APP /usr/local/bin/$APP
#export this actix web service to port 8080 and 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["mapservice"]
```

And when I run

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 mapservice
```

I got an error like:
`mapservice: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have no idea why would I got this error. Perhaps I have my APIKEY hardcoded in the main.rs??Does anyone know how to fix this problem? My laptop is M1pro Mac.

I try to run another sample project with a similar dockerfile, and everything is fine with it. I also tried to deploy it on AWS, which gives me another health check error on 8080. Is it something wrong with my docker file?

Comment: Note that OpenSSL 1.1 is _very_ old -- 3.x is current. Thus, in modern distros, installing `openssl` may be pulling in something much newer than 1.1.

Answer (score 3):

This error is because you have copied over the built executable to a new base image which does not have `libssl.so.1.1` installed. To fix, you'll need to install the dependency before the `CMD` step via a package install.

One way to fix this is to install the `openssl` package by adding `RUN apt-get update && apt install -y openssl` before the `CMD` step. You can also dive into installing just the libssl library itself, more info here: https://packages.debian.org/buster/libssl-dev. There are other packages which will also install this dependency. Ultimately the package chosen for installation will depend on your use case.

Comment: Use ```RUN apt-get update && apt install -y openssl``` not worked for me.
The part of my config is:
```
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update & apt-get install -y extra-runtime-dependencies openssl & rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/app /usr/local/bin/app
# cmd code here
```

Comment: Finally I make it works with debian:bullseye-slim image

Comment: doesn't this defeat a bit the purpose of a build image? `apt-get update` will bring some stuff, right?

Answer (score 3):

Using openssl as a dependency like

```
openssl = { version = "0.10.59", features = ["vendored"] }
```

did fix it for me

Comment: thanks, this helped me with Rust project when updated to Ubuntu 22.04 with above problem